# IE Context Menu Item In Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contextmenu

I am trying to create an IE Context Menu Item that points to a Javascript html file as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853(v=vs.85).aspx#IEAddOnsMenus_topic1
under the "Adding to a context menu" section. I have the Context menu entry listed in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt
and it points to an html file with javascript in it. Here is the Javascript code I am using.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function pausescript(ms) {
ms += new Date().getTime();
while (new Date() < ms){}
}      
{
var win = window.open("http://www.example.com");    
pausescript(2000);      
win.close();

}     
</script>
```

I am trying to pop up a window to the url then wait 2 seconds and close the window. It is working but when it closes the pop up window for some reason IE loses focus and any other window besides IE regains focus even though I am forcing the pop up from an IE context menu. How do I make IE get the focus after the pop up window closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is how to set the registry. I use windows 8.1 and I set the registry in this way:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
```

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\&Live Search]
@="C:\Usr\StackOverflow\livesearch.htm"
"Contexts"=dword:00000001

All worked fine (your script).

Like you can see the value of Contexts is different from the one described in the guide (instead of 0x10 i used 1).

It's unusefull to say you need to restart the browser.

**The FOCUS PROBLEM**

After closing the window poup window IE loses the focus.

Like described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853(v=vs.85).aspx#IEAddOnsMenus_topic1) you need to access external.menuArguments property to get the window handler of current ie.

So the javascript code is:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">

    function pausescript(ms) {
        ms += new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date() < ms){}
    }
    {
        var win = window.open("http://www.example.com");
        pausescript(2000);
        win.close();
        try {
            // access the current browser window
            var parentwin = external.menuArguments;

            // get the document element
            var doc = parentwin.document;

            // focus it
            doc.body.focus();
        } catch(ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That did not work. It works if you only have IE open but say you have notepad and IE both open. Click in notepad then go back to IE and Click the Context Menu Item. You will get the popup then as soon as the popup closes the notepad window pops up as the top most window even though the last window I clicked on is an IE window. How do I prevent this from happening and give the focus back to IE?

Comment: Another quick question, Is there a way to access the url without actually opening a window?

Comment: It should be: parentwin.location.href to access the current url

Comment: Any ideas as to why this would not work with Windows 10?

Comment: @carnick No, I use win8.1.  What I know is on Win10 ie11 is substituted with another product

Comment: This works in Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. For some reason in Windows 10 using IE 11 the focus does not go back to IE after the popup closes. Does anyone know how to regain the focus in IE in Windows 10 after the popup closes?