# Javascript how to get alt text of external div element

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="Thumbnail__thumbnail___3ABuK Thumb__thumbnail___jO6WM Video__thumbnail___2vJC9">
<img alt="alttext" src="https:/">
<div class="Duration__duration___qiPOI">14:57</div></div>
```

`window.external.menuArguments.event.srcElement.innerHTML;`

gives the above result.And then how to get the alt value of img ?

(I'm playing with internet explorer menuext function with

`window.ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")`

Comment: Provide id attribute to img tag, then use something like document.getElementById("myImg").alt to get alt value.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the page :) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920715/ie-context-menu-item-in-javascript)

Comment: You might want to know that `window.ActiveXObject` is a dead technology, so don't waste too much time on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the only way to do this is to manipulate the string;

```
var alt = window.external.menuArguments.event.srcElement.innerHTML;
if (alt.search("img alt=") > 0) alt = alt.substring(alt.lastIndexOf('img alt="') +9, alt.lastIndexOf('src') -2);
```

[04.07.2018] I finally found it;

```
window.external.menuArguments.event.srcElement.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
```